# Need to insert blank option in ddl before browser auto-selects

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working with a legacy asp.NET application that is dynamically building a ddl from deep inside the business layer or data layer. My problem is that if the ddl is set to be required in the application, it only presents the available selections, with no blank option at the top. This is causing users who overlook the selection to unknowingly submit the first option in the list as a "valid" selection, and never being notified. I can't get to this code server side, so I am trying to handle it client side with JQuery. I do have custom user controls on the page, so I can insert code through c# or the .ascx file through them if necessary.

What I have done so far is to write some JQuery that singles out these particular ddls, prepends a blank `<option>` to the `<select>`, then attempts to see if there are any items already marked as selected from the server, deciding whether or not to mark the new blank as the selected item. The code works, except for being able to determine if the server provided a selected option or not. I am using a $(document).ready function, thinking I would have access to manipulate the DOM before the browser renders it, but what I am finding is that when the server pushes out a ddl with no selected options (the source markup validates that none are marked as selected), by the time my JQuery runs, the first item in the list from the server has been set as selected (markup still shows none selected, but troubleshooting with a js alert reveals that the first item is indeed already marked as selected in the DOM). Is there any way for me to manipulate the ddl in DOM before the page default selects the first item? Here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[id*='ddl_field']").each(function () {
        var ddlVar = $(this).children(':first');
        var setDefault = true;
        $(this).children().each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected') {
                alert($(this).html() + ' is selected');
                setDefault = false;
            }
        });
        if (ddlVar.attr('value') == 0 && ddlVar.text() != "") {
            $(this).prepend("<option value=''></option>");
            if (setDefault == true)
                $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

The code above works, except it never evalutes the `if (setDefault == true)` as a true condition. Any ideas on what I am missing?

EDIT: Let me add that the actual markup is being build back in the c# data layer. The only thing I have access to in the user control is the table row that is being returned, pre-built with 2 columns, one with the label of the field being returned, and one with the input, in this case a ddl. I cannot get to the actual ddl server side, I can only manipulate at the row level.

Comment: Do you see: alert($(this).html() + ' is selected') ? Is the if (ddlVar.attr('value') == 0 && ddlVar.text() != "") { true?

Comment: Can't you just edit the markup and manually add the <option value="">Pick a category</option> right after the <select> ?

Comment: Irvin, Yes, the alert is my troubleshooting. The first html of the first option does pop up in the alert. And yes, the conditions for the containing if statement are met.

Comment: Travis, No, the markup is build back in either the Data Layer or Business layer. It is accessed with a simple call for a field, then it provides an entire table row, complete with label td and ddl td, pre-populated with available values. I am not defending the design practice they followed, but I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I gave up on this with JQuery. I ended up reflecting the code from the core code, bypassing and hardcoding the new functionality into my user control.